# Subtract the letters in a string

Tags: ocaml

operator (-): string → string → string that subtracts the letters in a string from the letters in another string, e.g., `"Walcw Cacdsa"-"abcwxyz"` will give `"Wlw Cds"` note that the operator - is case sensitive
I try with this code but don't work and tell me Syntax error.

```
let sub str =  
  for i = 0 to String.length str - 1 do 
    let string = Char.escaped str.[i] in 
    if string = "c" then str.replace(string, " ")  
    else let s3 = s3^string  
  done;;
```

Comment: There are many issues here. The `else` branch of your conditional expression has a `let` without an `in` and then an expression for `s3` to be local to. It looks like you're trying to call `replace` on `str` as though this is C++ or Java. I think maybe you need a good OCaml tutorial. You can see the OCaml tag wiki for some good links.

Comment: Also, as a general Stack Overflow tip: if you're getting an error, you should post that. _As text._

Comment: OCaml values are not OOP objects and don't have methods, so assuming `str` arg is a string value you can't `str.replace(string, " ")`. Also OCaml strings are immutable. You can probably do what you want without a for loop via a regex replace https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Str.html#1_Replacement

Comment: If you want a more functional approach or are prohibited by classroom requirement from using regular expressions, you can use `String.to_seq` to create a sequence of chars, which can be readily manipulated with the `Seq` module functions.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are an interesting thing to work with in OCaml. They're immutable meaning we have to create a new string rather than modifying the one passed in, but not readily pattern-matched. There are regular expressions, which make this kind of problem trivial, but it would be a lot easier if we had a list or sequence of characters, instead of a string.

Imagine if we had a list of integers and wanted to remove the integers in a second list from it using sequences.

```
let remove_ints lst lst_to_remove =
  lst
  |> List.to_seq
  |> Seq.filter 
       (fun x -> 
          lst_to_remove
          |> List.to_seq
          |> Seq.exists ((=) x)
          |> not)
  |> List.of_seq
```

Here the list is converted to a sequence, then filtered based on that int *not* appearing in a sequence created from the list of ints to remove. Finally, that filtered sequence is converted back into a list.

If I want to make this an operator (using `-` is a bad idea in practice but we'll use it for now), you can easily do that.

```
let (-) = remove_ints
```

```
utop # [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10] - [5; 6; 2];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 4; 7; 8; 9; 10]
```

This same logic can be applied to removing all of the characters in a string from another string. You simply need to convert a [string](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/String.html) to and from a [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html).

For efficiency, we might use a set to implement this. By converting the `lst_to_remove` list to a set, we can make lookups on it O(log n) vs. O(n), so that the function has O(m * log n) rather than O(m*n) runtime complexity.

```
module IntSet = Set.Make (Int)

let remove_ints lst lst_to_remove =
  let s = IntSet.of_list lst_to_remove in
  List.filter (fun i -> not @@ IntSet.mem i s) lst
```